# write a vscode extension visual test

Tags: visual-studio-code, automated-tests, vscode-extensions, visual-testing

I created a VSCode Extension and then I need to write some tests.
I am using Mocha and chai.
I wrote a few tests and I don't have any issue with that part. My problem is with the below scenario:

I have a button, when I press that button, an input box will appear and then I need to key in a value in the input box and press the okay button.

Can you help me with how I can simulate this scenario by a test? should simulate press the first button by calling the Command palette but how to key in value in the input box?
** Please take note that I already wrote the function test, but the user wants to test the UI also.

can you help me in finding an example related to my problem?

Comment: if you can't do it with mocks you need something like Selenium, just mock the GUI and clicking on the button

Comment: @rioV8, tq for your answer, I am familiar with Selenium, but it is with license am I right?
any sample for mock the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something like vscode-extension-tester which lets you test the GUI very comfortable. All information you can find on its github main page:
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/wiki